# What is this contact on a jack socket schematic?

Tags: connector, schematics, datasheet, trrs

I'm looking for a 4-poles (TRRS) 3.5mm jack socket with integrated switch, and stumbled upon this connector schematic:

[image: FC68129 schematic]

(this is an extract from the [CLIFF FC68129](http://www.cliffuk.co.uk/products/jacksockets/jacksockets4pole.pdf) datasheet)

I understand that pins 1, 2, 3 and 4 are respectively the sleeve, rings and tip contacts, and pin 6 the tip 
 normally-closed switch.

**What about pin 5 and its associated switch on pin 7?** The other pins already yield the right amount of connections for a TRRS jack socket.

My guess is that it could be some kind of "fully inserted plug" switch, but I cannot find the topmost "weird lengthy closed triangle" symbol in other datasheets.

[This seller](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/fc68129/jack-connectors/cliff/) has a 360° photo view of the connector, but it does not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that terminal 1 is the sleeve, 2 is first ring, 3 is second ring and 4 is tip.

6 is a switch contact normally connected to 4/tip contact when there is no plug inserted.

5 and 7 form an isolated switch, closed with no plug inserted, and not connected to any of the other terminals at any time.

Comment: That's my thoughts as well. Given the placement of the two switches arrow 5/7 would open before the tip switch. Do you have any source for that ?

Comment: @strnk: I wouldn't count on any particular order of operation of the switches - you're supposed to push the plug all the way in...